# @Input value treated as object instead of array

Tags: angular

In my parent component, I populate the array as follows:

```
myarray = [];
...
... // forloop
this.myarray.push({id: <someid>, name: <somename>});
```

In my parent template, I set this as input to the child

```
<childcomponent [myarray]="myarray"></childcomponent>
```

In my child component, I declare the input as:

```
@Input() myarray;
```

But when I tried to iterate and get the length, I cannot iterate and length is 0.  And then I tried to do "typeof" it returns an object.  I tried to write to console with console.log(myarray) and it gives me:

```
[]
0: {id: <someid>, name: <somename>}
```

Comment: can you create a stackblitz

Comment: you can use @Input() myarray = new Array<any>(); it should work

Comment: it doesn't work.  still cannot iterate

Comment: it is straight forward. I assume there is something wrong in other place. can you create a stackblitz so that others can help. you can create it from https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: yah, i discovered it.  it's because i'm populating the array after subscribing to a service.. in this case, i put an `*ngIf=myarray` in the child html so it will render only when myarray is ready

Answer (score 1):

The Array in JavaScript is a global object which contains a list of items.

[Please take a look at my demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnyxzb)

You can specify type as Array to make object iterable.

Comment: Hmm, do I really need to do that in the child component?  I thought it should be just straightforward assignment.

Comment: Yes dev, as I mentioned Array in JavaScript is a global object. So type casting is required to use its functionality. After all type specification is newly supported in angular with Typescript.

Comment: I tried to do this but still won't iterate.  Could it be because I populate the array after subscribing to a http service?

Comment: yah, this is the reason why.  I need to put the `ngIf=myarray` to wait for the array to be populated.  i think no need to do what you did in the demo.  thanks anyways

Comment: Yes it could be blank object before http service call. However if you specify type of array manually, then "you won't get error in *ngFor" that is what I want to convey.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with your code.
If you open google console, create an array, e.g

```
let a = [];
typeof(a); // "object"
```

Initially, the element which you are passing to your input is an empty array, 
then you are pushing some items into it, so if you observe you have two states of the array which you are passing to the Input: 1.Empty, 2. Some Objects which you pushed in the array.

If you subscribe to the input and console log its value, you will get two different outputs.

```
  @Input()
  public set myArray(myArray: Array<any>) {
    if (myArray) {
      console.log(myArray);
    }
  }
```

It will console.log the value of myArray when ever there is any change in the value

Comment: even if I do this, and try to iterate inside your `if (myArray)`, i still won't be able to iterate

Comment: can you create a demo at stackblitz.